# XDS.b testing with SoapUI

Tags: soap, soapui, mtom, mirth

I have to implement a simple client to a XDS.b server (SubmitObjectRequest and RetrieveDocumentSetRequest operations), but I'm struggling to get even a simple example of use to work.

I've tried using [Mirth Connect's Channel for XDS.b](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/MR/XDS.b+Support) also, but with no use. I even tried to copy its SOAP envelope to use with SoapUI. Didn't work.

I'm using [HIEOS](https://kenai.com/projects/hieos) deployed on Glassfish as my XDS.b server.

I'm lost and confused. Could anyone give me a guidance on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

If the HIEOS is deployed correctly within the Glassfish the service endpoint provides a wsdl definition where the interface is specified. Check the Glassfish for the wsdl of the service.

```
http://localhost:8080/my-ws/simple?WSDL
Quelle: docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/gbiyw.html
```

The list of provided endpoints you can see here:

```
https://kenai.com/projects/hieos/pages/WebServices
```

So to retrieve the wsdl you should use for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/xdsrepositoryb?wsdl
```

which applies for the ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSet-b transaction of the XDS Repository actor.

You can use the WSDL definition to create a WS request using SOAP UI at first.

[image]

SOAP UI creates a request based upon the wsdl definition which can be used to 
test a against your XDS repo.

When you know how a SOAP request must be constructed you can try it using Mirth or
create your own client using Apache CXF http://cxf.apache.org/ for example.
Or you use AXIS2 to create a client from the WSDL. Of course does Visual Studio and C# also offer mechanisms to create a WS client directly from a WSDL definition.

Comment: I think I didn't expressed myself very well. This thing you posted was the very first thing I did. What I need is how do you send those files to HIEOS XDS.b server. Could you please complete your answer providing more details on request? I wouldn't put 100 rep points to get such a simple answer :-)

Comment: Thats a pitty :-). To give a sophisticated answer i would have to install complete Glassfish with HIEOS. I just can refer to http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/reference.html which explains how to add a binary attachment with SOAP UI using MTOM.

Comment: You may also have a look at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/mtom.html which shows how to enable MTOM using Java language and the Apache CXF WebService framework.

Comment: I've already done that. I tried to attach binary files using MTOM.  Tried so many times and in so different ways that I do not know how can I make it work. That's why I said I'm lost and that's why I asked for a *complete* example in order to see where I'm doing wrong. I appreciate your effort and I'll keep trying to solve this problem.

Comment: I just saw your question and the reps for it yesterday. I will try to get to work completely. Give me three days or better lets say friday. I have some experience using mirth. I know about Apache CXF and SOAP and all the problems around it.